# Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\laragon\www\index.php on line 92 Notice: Undefined index: active in C:\laragon\www\index.php on line 243

Tags: php, session-variables

i get this error ?????
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\laragon\www\index.php on line 92

Notice: Undefined index: active in C:\laragon\www\index.php on line 243

```
if ($_SESSION['active']) {
$IfWwKRkbZJLElhgkWJxK = preg_replace('/<!--HEADER-->(.*?)<!--MAIN-->/is', $wxblPyOWmDcyrjnDFW, $zakSEsduePXkDfniPezC);
echo $IfWwKRkbZJLElhgkWJxK;
echo "<script>                               $('#sexx').val('true');                                                               </script>";
```

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['active']) && $_SESSION['active'])` and do the same with whatever you tried to access on line 92

Answer (score 0):

This means active doesn't exist within the session.
You could use isset e.g.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['active']) && $_SESSION['active'])) {
```

Or empty

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['active'])) {
```